# connections to postgresql at particular time frame

Tags: postgresql, database, database-administration, database-performance

How can i find the connections made/utilized to my PostgreSQL at a particular given time frame ?

In the PostgreSQL logs i am getting

```
JSTERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Sar logs :

```
MEM      AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
09:00:01 AM  25773712  40158364     60.91    257512  35876668   4552540      5.53
09:10:01 AM  25728656  40203420     60.98    258080  35920500   4555720      5.53
```

Some config settings:

```
max_connections = 2000
superuser_reserved_connections = 3
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 128MB
work_mem = 1GB
maintenance_work_mem = 16MB
```

How can i troubleshoot this?

Advice welcome.

Comment: You said connection, but do you mean query? For example a connection pool may open a connection, then reuse it 100s of times for unrelated clients and queries before closing it. And why didn't you try configuring the logging on the postgres server?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly but generally speaking PostgreSQL so far ( pg 9.6 2016/12) does not show any history of these statistics. Therefore I use monitoring with postgresql_exporter + prometheus + Grafana to see some metrics history - standard setting on prometheus is 15 days. In combination with node_exported you can see also metrics of OS. New Grafana 4.0 has even alerting. And you can run all these components in docker without necessity to install anything directly - I highly recommend it.